# JOOQ JsonbValue in where()

Tags: java, postgresql, jooq

Working on trying to convert the following Postgres Query into Jooq. I would love to implement this with JOOQ's features instead of just copying the SQL in.

Ultimately im trying to make this query in jooq.

```sql
SELECT * from content_block cb 
JOIN content_block_data cbd on cbd.block_id  = cb.id 
WHERE cbd."data" @? '$.** ? (@.blockId == 120)';
```

Another instance of a similar query

```sql
SELECT *
FROM content_block_data
WHERE jsonb_path_query_first(data, '$.**.blockId') @> '120';
```

Another instance of a similar query

```sql
SELECT *
FROM content_block_data
WHERE jsonb_path_exists(data, '$.** ? (@.blockId == 120)');
```

What I have in java

```java
    @NotNull 
Result<Record> parentBlockRecords =
        dslContext.select(asterisk()).from(CONTENT_BLOCK_DATA
            .join(CONTENT_BLOCK).on(CONTENT_BLOCK.ID.eq(CONTENT_BLOCK_DATA.BLOCK_ID)))
            //.where(jsonbValue(CONTENT_BLOCK_DATA.DATA,"$.**.blockId").toString()
             //   .contains(String.valueOf(blockId)))
            .fetch();
```

The where on this im having a hard time getting to work. The query can grab data from the DB, but just having a fair bit of trouble with this comparison.

And idea of the data in CONTENT_BLOCK_DATA.DATA

```json
{
  "blocks": [
    {
      "blockId": 120,
      "__source": "block"
    },
    {
      "blockId": 122,
      "__source": "block"
    }
  ]
}
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for Jooq's [jsonValue](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/column-expressions/json-functions/json-value-function/) and [jsonExists](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/conditional-expressions/json-exists-predicate/), which correspond to PostgreSQL's `jsonb_path_query_first` amd `jsonb_path_exists`.

*Also note that the `@?` operator is equivalent to the `jsonb_path_exists` function with the `silent` flag set. See the note after the [JSON operator table in the PostgreSQL documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-OP-TABLE).*

---

For your first example, you would use the following:

```java
  .join(/* */)
  .where(jsonExists(CONTENT_BLOCK_DATA.DATA, "$.** ? (@.blockId == 120)"))
  .fetch();
```

For the second example, I couldn't find a Jooq DSL symbol that corresponds to the `@>` jsonb containment operator, so you might have to fallback to [plain SQL in JOOQ](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql/), like so:

```java
// Second example
  .from(/* */)
  .where(condition("{0} @> {1}",
    jsonValue(CONTENT_BLOCK_DATA.DATA, "$.**.blockId"),
    JSONB.valueOf(120)));
  .fetch();
```

*Based on the solution presented here: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/13125.*

Comment: I did see this on my searches, but was hoping for a way without using @> or the workaround for it. Seems like it doesn't exist yet. Thanks.
One slight update to the above is you are mixing json and jsonb things methods. 
For instance in the second code block you use jsonValue and JSONB.valueOf